Is there any way to use classic and custom components in the same Azure Machine Learning pipeline?
I am trying to migrate a pipeline from Microsoft machine learning studio classic to Azure machine learning.  My pipeline which is actually running on Machine Learning Studio Classic and is composed by the following components which are classic and custom. The input data are six and are collected from a blob storage account using the import data component. They are mainly csv files and i use a custom component which is an R script to clean the input data. This is because the “Execute R Script“ allows only 2 inputs but i need 6 as i have 6 input files. After that, the csv files are written into the same blob storage account but in another folder using a component called export data. I want to build the same pipeline into azure machine learning can I use custom and default components in the same pipeline?
If I try to create a pipeline with classic components apparently I can‘t use my custom component (A.K.A. R Script) and when I try to create a custom pipeline I can‘t use the classic components and apparently there is no way to export my data when creating a custom pipeline after my custom component cleans the input data.

Add your r script how you using 6 dataframe for cleaning.

The script cleans 6 data frames, I‘m not using 6 data frames for cleaning

There are multiple ways to handle this scenario:

Create data assets in Azure ML Studio from these six files.


Here, you can create a single data asset from the 6 files and use it in a component like below.


If you need to clean these files separately using different logic, create 6 separate data assets and access them in an R script like below. Then, clean and register them as data assets in Azure ML.

azureml_main <- function(dataframe1, dataframe2){
  print("R script run.")
  run = get_current_run()
  ws = run$experiment$workspace
  dataset1 = azureml$core$dataset$Dataset$get_by_name(ws, "output_dataset_name")
  dataset2 = azureml$core$dataset$Dataset$get_by_name(ws, "sql")
  #load all your data asset
  #clean your data
  dataframe1 <- dataset$to_pandas_dataframe()
  # Return datasets as a Named List
  return(list(dataset1=dataframe1, dataset2=dataframe2))
}



You can also use the 3-argument or port Script Bundle where you create a data asset using a .zip file containing all your files. These files are extracted and available in runtime under ./Script Bundle. Use the code below to read your files.

azureml_main <- function(dataframe1, dataframe2){
  print("R script run.")
  mydataset<-read.csv("./Script Bundle/mydatafile.csv",encoding="UTF-8");  
  # clean and return
  return(list(dataset1=mydataset, dataset2=dataframe2))
}

To create a data asset using a zip file, follow these steps.
Refer to this documentation for more information about the R component and its usage.
You can also refer this github documentation on how to load csv files as tabular data asset, cleaning them  and register it as data asset with out need of export data component.
